# How can I create Cursor (or other Read + Seek object) over Arc<Vec> in Rust?

Tags: rust, stream, iterator

The actual problem (to avoid A/B scenario):

I have a large buffer behind Arc object:

```rust
pub struct LargeData {
    data: Arc<Vec<u8>>,
}
```

I need to pass `Read + Seek` version to network API as the Box'ed return from the function (without copying the entire buffer).

Firstly I tried just making Cursor over reference to Vec:

```rust
fn open_for_read(&self) -> io::Result<Box<dyn ReadAndSeek>> {
    Ok(Box::new(Cursor::new(self.data.as_ref())))
}
```

But the compiler correctly warned about this cursor may actually outlive all ARC instances.

My second though would be to pack both `Cursor` and `Arc` into new struct and implement `Read + Seek` for it

```rust
struct ReaderData {
    data: Arc<Vec<u8>>,
    cursor: Cursor<Vec<u8>>,
}

impl ReaderData {
    fn new(source: &LargeData) -> Self {
        let data = source.data.clone();
        Self {
            data,
            cursor: Cursor::new(data),
        }
    }
}
// Read + Seek implementation that only passes into cursor Read and Seek
```

But this time I've got more enigmatic error:

```
cursor: Cursor::new(data),
        ----------- ^^^^- help: try using a conversion method: `.to_vec()`
        |           |
        |           expected `Vec<u8>`, found `Arc<Vec<u8>>`
        arguments to this function are incorrect
```

Using `to_vec()` would make a copy of vector which is what I wanted to avoid.

This is a place where I gave up.

Am I missing something here? How can I make `Read + Seek` object from `Arc<Vec<u8>>` ?

Comment: Just adding a `'_` is enough: `io::Result<Box<dyn ReadAndSeek + '_>>`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I've got an error that this is altering a trait I am trying to implement. The question is wouldn't it force `LargeData` to live long enough for the cursor object (which may not be the case, the object may be dropped elsewhere and ARC must survive that)?

Comment: If `fn open_for_read()` is part of a trait, please post that trait definition. `io::Result<Box<dyn ReadAndSeek>>` is [implicitly](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1156-adjust-default-object-bounds.html) `io::Result<Box<dyn ReadAndSeek + 'static>>`, and the `'_` allows for lifetime elision to kick in an shorten that to the lifetime of `&self`. It should work, there should even be a help message about it when the error is raised.

Comment: @user2722968 My mistake, I was absolutely sure this would force `LargeData` to outlive results of `open_for_read()`... I've asked for an API trait change, and it was accepted by my collegue.

@ChayimFriedman Can you post your comment as answer, so I can accept that?

Comment: @PiotrK, it does: The function implicitly becomes `fn open_for_read<'a>(&'a self) -> io::Result<Box<dyn ReadAndSeek + '_a>>`. That is, the result is only valid as long as the `LargeData` instance it came from is alive. The cursor-proxy doesn't own an independent `Arc`-instance... Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you last said here.

Comment: @user2722968 Okay, so how can I implement `open_for_read` so it does not require `LargeData` to exists anymore? I mean, the returned object must (?) own an independent clone of Arc, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. The `Cursor` inside `Box` will keep it's state about "where" it currently is with respect to the underlying buffer. But that buffer is a `&[u8]`, so the object in it's entirety has a lifetime associated with it that can't be shorter than the lifetime of that `&[u8]`. The way as described above guarantees that this lifetimes is at least as long as `&self`. `LargeData` can't get dropped while it is borrowed. In fact,  it can't be modified at all. But all of that is fine, as long as you don't **require** that `Cursor`-like object to be independent.

Comment: @user2722968
LargeData may come from other thread and may be dropped there as well. So I believe I pretty much require this cursor to be independent... :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256441/discussion-between-user2722968-and-piotrk).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Cursor` requires the type to implement `AsRef<[u8]>`. `Arc<Vec<u8>>` unfortunately does not, but you can impl it yourself for `LargeData`:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct LargeData {
    data: Arc<Vec<u8>>,
}

impl AsRef<[u8]> for LargeData {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &[u8] {
        &self.data
    }
}

impl LargeData {
    fn open_for_read(&self) -> Cursor<LargeData> {
        Cursor::new(self.clone())
    }
}
```

If `LargeData` contains other fields, you can extract the `Arc<Vec<u8>>` to a different struct.

Comment: I missed the `impl AsRef<[u8]> for LargeData` part from docs. Thanks!